# Specification of DFA accepting ≡∪∈N

Tags: complexity-theory, context-free-grammar, regular-language, computation-theory, context-free-language

Why it is impossible to specify a single DFA that accepts ≡∪∈N, although an individual machine can be constructed for each ?

Comment: You might find better help over at [cs.se] given the nature of this question.

Comment: Because there is an infinite number of values of N, and you cannot combine an **infinite** set of different automata into a **finite**-state machine.

Comment: What are the Ln here? For some infinite sequences of languages L1, L2, ..., the infinite union of the languages is a regular language that has a DFA. But in general such languages are not regular.